# Docusignapi disclosure check box before Review Document button

Tags: docusignapi

Where do I hide the checkbox and the content below that is shown in the disclosure page for embedded signing case. ? 
"Check here to confirm you have reviewed and agree to our Consent Statement."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the checkbox and the "I agree to do business electronically with..." statement that appears below the consumer disclosure statement on the popup dialog window that appears when the signing session is first initiated -- I don't believe it's possible to remove this checkbox and statement altogether.  But, you can customize the statement by modifying the Signing Resource file (as described in the Branding guide: http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Quick%20Start%20-%20Account%20Branding.pdf).  In the Signing Resource file, the element names for modifying the statement are **DocuSign_IntroAgree** and **DocuSign_IntroAgree_Mobile**.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify some of those buttons using the resource files, but you need to be careful.  For instance ability to decline to sign is a right that you can't take away from the user.  When dealing with legal documents you need to give people the option to review, make a decision and then proceed with signing only if they are ready to commit to the terms.

PS: I am not a lawyer, just been in eSignature business for 7+ years.